# Changes made to Spark scala code base are not reflected at runtime

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'll start off by saying that I am a beginner to Scala. I cloned the Spark source code from Github and am playing around, peeking under the hood because I am curious about Spark's internal workings.

However, it doesn't appear as if any changes I make to the code base are reflected when I rebuild and run Spark. For instance, in the `spark-shell` REPL, initialization will print

`Spark context Web UI available at [some address and port]`. This portion comes from `repl.src.main.scala.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.scala` ([link to Github here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/repl/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/repl/SparkILoop.scala)), as part of the `initializationCommands` value.

I performed the following steps:

1. I tried simply adding `println(s"Spark context Web UI available at
   ${webUrl}!!!!"` to print extra exclamation points for this message.
2. I ran `build/sbt clean package`, which completed successfully.
3. I started my Spark shell with `bin/spark-shell`, expecting that my
   exclamation points would appear in the console. They did not. I got
   the same exact default message as before (without the exclamation points).

Not to be discouraged, I noticed that `18/11/28 08:09:20 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable` is often printed as a logging message when Spark (and Spark shell) first loads on local machines w/out Hadoop. So clearly, it's able to log warning messages.

I attempted to replicate this by adding a simple logging message to the `SparkContext` constructor in the [SparkContext class definition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala), since I know this is initialized and available as `sc` within the Spark shell. I edited the following lines in

```
class SparkContext(config: SparkConf) extends Logging {

  logWarning("Hello!!!!")
  /* rest of the constructor code is below */
```

Again, I followed the same procedure of cleaning and building, and expected to see some logging message with `Hello!!!!` in my console.

Again, I see the default warning message for not having native Hadoop, but not my own message.

I apologize for what is probably a very newbish question, but what exactly do I need to do to get my own source code changes to show on runtime? I'm also not fairly certain what information I should be attaching as well to assist people answering my question- and would be more than happy to provide.

Comment: Do you have another spark installation?

Comment: @sramalingam24 i do, but I’ve changed my SPARK_HOME variable to point to this cloned repo. Plus, shouldn’t it not matter since I’m directly calling bin/spark-shell from the project root directory?

Comment: Can you try running again after killing spark context?

Comment: Delete or rename the other spark directory and try running it

Comment: @sramalingam24 turned out to be a silly mistake on my part. I changed my environment variables but never sourced my bash profile so it was still calling the old bash. If you'd like you can write this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Cool,. You can just post the answer and Mark it so, since you figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a silly mistake on my part. I had an existing Spark installation set up and configured (for actual work, not doodling around). I changed my environment variables but never sourced my bash profile. To be explicit, you should

```
export SPARK_HOME=path/to/your/spark/source/code
```

then, `source ~/.bash_profile` or wherever you store your environment variables.

I never sourced, so when typing `spark-shell`, it was still pointing to my existing Spark installation.